# Detect number of different strings in Array

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

**Basically I need a function which counts the amount of different values in an array and one other function to give me the actual count of each different value in my array.**

I have an Array which contains a changing amount of values:

Array = (This, This, This, This, Is, Is, Is, Is, Is, It, It, It, It)

I want to make a list view, each section should contain the different categories like:

```
This
- Element 1
- Element 2
- ...
Is
- Element 1
- ...
It
- Element 1
- ...
```

So I need the number **3** for my number of sections and the number of *child-elements* for each section.

How can I achieve that? Is there a better way than a for-statement with counting indexes for each section?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add each array element to an `NSCountedSet`.  Then the `count` of the set is the number of distinct objects you added, and you can use `countForObject:` to ask the set how many there are of each distinct object.

Comment: Problem: I don't know the actual string. It is dynamic.

Comment: I don't understand why that's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, make o copy of your array, to work with.

1. To count different values, remove all duplicates from the copied
   array, and copiedArray.count will tell you what you need. (search on
   your own how to remove duplicates).
2. To get the actual count of each group: you have the copied array already without duplicates, so make a for loop within the copied array:

   `for (NSString *stringer in copiedArrayWithoutDuplicates){`

   ```
      int counter = 0;
      for(NSString *iniStr in initialArrayWithDuplicates){
         if([stringer isEqualToString: iniStr]){
             counter++;
         }
      }
      NSLog(@"string %@ was detected %i times", stringer, counter);
   }
   ```

Comment: Problem: I don't know the actual string. It is dynamic.

Comment: ahh, sorry, so you need to detect similar strings? like you would have the array with strings that were duplicated?

Comment: Yes. It's a JSON answer with some links which have categories. I want to display the list of links under each category. It is an app update so I don't want to change my PHP file. But maybe I have to to give back a better array.